# Is there electric potential outside a grounded sphere with charge inside?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential

Say I have a point charge put inside a grounded sphere. The rest of space is charge-free. Is there still any electric potential outside the sphere?

Comment: "Grounded" is commonly understood as "at zero potential".

Comment: What do you think? (Show some effort.)

Comment: Here's my thought: Since the potential would be coming from the charge inside the grounded sphere, and it would be zero at the grounded sphere, there should be zero potential outside the grounded sphere too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by Gauss’ law there is an E-field outside the sphere and therefore there is a spatially varying potential.

Note, by your description the sphere must be an uncharged sphere of a non-conductive material

Comment: Once you ground the sphere it doesn't stay uncharged. (Or if it does, that's because it's a nonconducting material, so grounding it is meaningless)

Comment: Yes. It must be non-conducting since there are no charges other than the point charge and a conducting sphere would have surface charges. I agree that grounding a non-conducting sphere is pointless

Comment: I don't see where the problem statement says there's no charge on the sphere. It only says "the rest of space" is charge free. take that to mean the space outside the sphere, but not to imply the sphere is charge free.

Comment: I take it to include the sphere.

Comment: A question: Can't we picture the grounded sphere as if they were points at infinity, thus the electric field and potential are zero there?

Comment: @Len only if you allow the sphere to become charged

Answer (score 0):

If it is a grounded sphere, the potential on the surface of the sphere will be zero. Then, by the uniqueness theorem, the potential and field outside the sphere will be zero.